# とあるHTMLページの指定範囲だけマウスで選択できないのですが、理由は？

Tags: html

[このページ](https://shibuya.parco.jp/floor/)で、B1F「個性的な専門店」などの範囲がマウスで選択できないのですが、なぜですか？
aタグで囲われているから？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**aタグで囲われているから？**

おそらくそうでしょう。
( **追記** それに加えて複雑なデザインにしているのも関係しているようです)

例えばこのサイトの質問記事タイトルは一つのaタグになっていて、先頭あるいは末尾からは選択出来ますが、途中部分「HTMLページの指定範囲」だけを選択することは出来ません。
それと類似なことだと思われます。
( **追記** 文字の間にマウス開始位置を置くのでは出来ませんでしたが、aタグの外側で`H`の直上あたりを開始位置にすると途中部分だけ選択出来ました)

ただし参照ページの質問内容の「B1F」「CHAOS KITCHEN」「RESTAURANT, CAFÉ, BAR, GOODS, GALLERY」「個性的な専門店」～以後はその中でもタグ(div,p,h2)が分かれているので、表示位置が分かれていれば選択は可能かもしれませんが、「個性的な専門店」だけの位置から選択を開始するのは無理そうです。
( **追記** 上記追記と同様にaタグの外側で`個`の直上あたりを開始位置にしてもダメで、下記の「マウス開始位置を「フロアガイド」の右にした場合」と同様になりました。色々とデザインを凝っている関係でしょうか)

それらをコピペした結果は以下の文字列になっていました。

- マウス開始位置を「フロアガイド」の右にした場合

```
B1F

CHAOS KITCHEN
RESTAURANT, CAFÉ, BAR, GOODS, GALLERY

個性的な専門店
```

- マウス開始位置を「B1F」の左にした場合

```
B1F

CHAOS KITCHEN
RESTAURANT, CAFÉ, BAR, GOODS, GALLERY

個性的な専門店
```

- マウス開始位置を「CHAOS KITCHEN」の左にした場合

```
CHAOS KITCHEN
RESTAURANT, CAFÉ, BAR, GOODS, GALLERY

個性的な専門店
```

- マウス開始位置を「RESTAURANT, CAFÉ, BAR, GOODS, GALLERY」の左にした場合
  および「RESTAURANT, CAFÉ, BAR, GOODS, GALLERY」の下左にしても同じ

```
RESTAURANT, CAFÉ, BAR, GOODS, GALLERY

個性的な専門店
```

- マウス開始位置を「個性的な専門店」の左(B1F等との間)にした場合
  **→ドラッグ状態になって選択できない**
- あるいはマウス開始位置を「CHAOS KITCHEN」の左にしてその文字列だけを選択した場合

```
CHAOS KITCHEN
```

Comment: CSSの user-select プロパティを真っ先に疑ったのですが見つからず、変だなと思い質問しました。複雑な構成だと、(結果として)選択できないこともあるのですね。参考になりました

Answer (score 0):

ホバー時のエフェクト (=セル全体に色が付く) で分かりづらくなっていますが、実際には特に問題なく範囲選択できています。

選択後にマウスカーソルを別の場所に移動してみてください。
(選択された状態から文字列のコピーも実行できています)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]